# how to make fragment singleton using navigatio and dagger2?

Tags: android

I'm using fragment navigation using dagger2. I need to make a fragment singleton.although I added @Singleton annotation at ApplicationComponent, it didn't work. for making a fragment singleton, I have to give up using dagger2 and fragment navigation? testing the lifecycle, my fragment is called "onActivityCreated" many times. I can't controll replacing fragment because I use nav_graph. so I can't use fragment replace.

*HomeFragment*

```
class HomeFragment : DaggerFragment() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory
    private val viewModel by viewModels<HomeViewModel> { viewModelFactory }
    private lateinit var viewDataBinding: FragmentHomeBinding

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        viewDataBinding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false).apply {
            viewmodel = viewModel
        }
        return view
    }


    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        viewDataBinding.lifecycleOwner = this.viewLifecycleOwner
        Log.d("TAG","HomeFragment onCreate")
        init()
        viewModel.getNotice()
    }

    private fun init(){
        viewModel.notice.observe(this, Observer{
            noticeMain.text = it

        })
    }

}
```

*HomeModule*

```
@Module
abstract class HomeModule {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [
        ViewModelBuilder::class
        ])


    internal abstract fun homeFragment(): HomeFragment

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(HomeViewModel::class)
    abstract fun bindViewModel(viewmodel: HomeViewModel): ViewModel
}
```

*ApplicationModule*

```
@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = [
        ApplicationModule::class,
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
        RegisterModule::class,
        HomeModule::class,
        SecondModule::class
    ])
interface ApplicationComponent : AndroidInjector<GlobalApplication> {

    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(@BindsInstance applicationContext: Context): ApplicationComponent
    }
}
```

*nav_graph*

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:startDestination="@+id/homeFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:name="com.haii.loginproject.fragment.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="Home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment_to_secondFragment"
            app:destination="@id/secondFragment" />

    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/secondFragment"
        android:name="com.haii.loginproject.fragment.second.SecondFragment"
        android:label="Second"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_second">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_secondFragment_to_homeFragment"
            app:destination="@id/homeFragment" />

    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

Comment: If you need to make a Fragment a singleton, you are doing something *very* wrong because the system recreates it later on therefore that's just not going to work that way.

Comment: To make a fragment singleton, Do I have to give up dagger2 and navigation?

Comment: You cannot make a Fragment a singleton at all.